# Hartl's Rails Tutorial chapter 7 exercise 2. I'm stuck creating the test for error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to create the test for the error messages that show if invalid data is entered into the signup form for Michael Hartls' rails tutorial exercise 2.  He provides as a "suggested start":

```
describe "signup" do

 before { visit signup_path }
 .
 .
 .
  describe "with invalid information" do
   .
   .
   .
   describe "after submission" do
     before { click_button submit }

     it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
     it { should have_content('error') }
   end
```

My thought was to add something after the 'error'.  But that hasn't worked so far.  Using just above I get the RSpec error message:

```
1) UserPages signup with invalid information after submission it should 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('error') }
   expected css "error" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:37:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've blown through the tutorial until this point.  And I thought I had the tests down the most! Suggestions?

Comment: The code you've shown and the error don't match up.

Comment: As Paul mentions, the error message is about `have_selector('error')` and the code has `have_selector('title'..)` & `have_content('error')`; they don't match up. Do check the code at line #37 in `./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` which is pointed by the error trace.

Comment: You're right.  It was the fact I didn't save the change I made up top.  Haha!  Thanks for the fresh eyes!

Comment: We've all been there :-)  If that was the issue, please then answer your own question and mark it as accepted for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow and to the Rails community.

It's great that you're learning to write automated tests.  The first thing you should try doing is visiting this page of the webapp you're building in your browser.  Can you trigger the validation error you're expecting?  Do you see it on the page with the CSS error class applied to it's container?  You can check all of these with a web inspector/debugger tool.

The error you're seeing means that the automated test is expecting to find a DOM element on the page with the CSS class "error", but no elements are being returned.

I bet if you view the page yourself you can figure out why it's not triggering the validation error and view display you expect.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I checked it out using Firebug (which I'm still getting used to) and was able to fix the problem.

Comment: Great.  I'm glad you worked out the problem.  Do you mind accepting this answer since it sounds like it lead you to your solution?